# AWS EMR Mapreduce failure

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an installation of AWS EMR in a client environment. The encryption in transit and the encryption at rest has been enabled using security configuration. We continue to get the below mapreduce errors when we execute a simple Hive query.

Diagnostic Messages for this Task:

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError:
>   error in shuffle in fetcher#1
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:377)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>                   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>                   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.ShuffleSchedulerImpl.checkReducerHealth(ShuffleSchedulerImpl.java:366)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.ShuffleSchedulerImpl.copyFailed(ShuffleSchedulerImpl.java:288)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.openShuffleUrl(Fetcher.java:282)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:323)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:193)

Please let me know if anyone has faced this error before.

Comment: were you able to solve your issue?